# Blocked by CORS Policy - S3 Bucket Access from Django App

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I am having an issue with my application accessing the font files in my S3 bucket.

Here is my CORS Policy on the S3 bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

But in the console when accessing my website I am getting the following:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource

Comment: You've cleared your browser cache?  Can you capture a failed request/response with headers, from the browser and edit it into the question?

Comment: Same issue here how did you fix this?

Comment: did anyone find an answer?

Comment: I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually configured a CloudFront distribution with whitelisted `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, with the origin as S3, and configured nginx to include the right headers.

The Origin request header indicates where a fetch originates from. It doesn't include any path information,
but only the server name (e.g. https://www.example.com).
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin for details.

Here we set the value that is included in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. If the origin is one of our known hosts--served via HTTP or HTTPS--we allow for CORS. Otherwise, we set the "null" value, disallowing CORS.

```
map $http_host $cors_origin {
default "null";
  "~*^\.example\.com$" "$http_x_forwarded_proto://$http_host";
}
```